# Add html if value label is something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a login page and i want customize it...
the page is created by other code, so i want customize with jquery adding an external file. 
In this case i want do add a string before a login form, and so BEFORE the label where value is username...

But doesn't work...

```
    if($('label').val()== "Username*"){
         $(this).before('<h1>Effettua il login:</hi><br>');
      }
```

This is jsfiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fw6nong1/2/

Comment: i tried also that... but nothing :(

Comment: Replace your code with this: `$("label:contains('Username')").before('<h1>Effettua il login:</hi><br>');`

Comment: A label has no value attribute/property. It could but it would be invalid regarding W3C spec

Comment: @Arg0n works! ;) write an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the label by its for attribute.

```js
 var linkelimina = self.location.href;
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var link = self.location.href;
     if (link == linkelimina || link == "http://www.webisite.com/user" || link == "http://www.website.com/user/password") {
         $('.tabs').css('display', 'none');
         $('.description').css('display', 'none');
         
        
           $('label[for="edit-name"]').before('<h1>Effettua il login:</hi><br>');
          
     }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section"> <a id="main-content"></a> 
    <div class="tabs">
         <h2 class="element-invisible">Primary tabs</h2>

        <ul class="tabs primary">
            <li><a href="/user/register">Create new account</a>

            </li>
            <li class="active"><a class="active" href="/user">Log in<span class="element-invisible">(active tab)</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="/user/password">Request new password</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="region region-content">
        <div class="block block-system" id="block-system-main">
            <div class="content">
                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="user-login" method="post" action="/user">
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
                            <label for="edit-name">Username <span title="This field is required." class="form-required">*</span>

                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-text required" maxlength="60" size="60" value="" name="name" id="edit-name">
                            <div class="description">Enter your website username.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
                            <label for="edit-pass">Password <span title="This field is required." class="form-required">*</span>

                            </label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-text required" maxlength="128" size="60" name="pass" id="edit-pass">
                            <div class="description">Enter the password that accompanies your username.</div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="form-l7DnfqR5ZJej8oGkHS8x_9YmAzOYnFX0qxiuSxY5XZI" name="form_build_id">
                        <input type="hidden" value="user_login" name="form_id">
                        <div id="edit-actions" class="form-actions form-wrapper">
                            <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Log in" name="op" id="edit-submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no because there are two same labe attribute.... is possibile select is by text ?

Comment: @user3162975 I dont see that... the one has the value of edit-name and the other edit-pass making them individually selectable but I will extend the answer to include text.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/vgenezkf/) JSFiddle:

I replaced your code with

```
$("label:contains('Username')").before('<h1>Effettua il login:</hi><br>');
```

**EDIT**

```
$("label[for='edit-name']").before('<h1>Effettua il login:</hi><br>');
```

Also works fine, just replace the selector with something unique for the label containing "Username *"

Comment: This would match `<label>whatever Username and whatelse</label>` too. Not always expected behaviour. Better is to filter it regarding label text matching exactly string or regarding some specific attribute, as `data-*` one

Comment: Then use another selector, like `$("label[for='edit-name']").before('<h1>Effettua il login:</hi><br>');`

Comment: Ya, seems better imho

Answer (score 0):

To filter it by text, you can use:

```
$("label").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Username"; // trimming text because you have extra space
}).before('<h1>Effettua il login:</hi><br>');
```